# Window Closing Event and KeyPress

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<Window Closing="Window_Closing"></Window>
```

Assuming keys are used to close the window.  Is there a way to determine which keys were used?

I know you can with the KeyDown event but need to do so in the Closing event.

Thank you!

Comment: Closing can occur from a lot more than a key press.  It could be closed with a mouse click, End Task from task manager, system shutting down, etc.  There is no way to determine what keyboard stroke caused a closing event since it's not directly related.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @NathanA Basically it's a WPF application that opens a WebBrowser object in full screen.  I want to eliminate as many methods to close the application as possible.  Such as disable alt+f4 which I've done through KeyDown.  I could use e.Cancel=true in closing but then it would also not close the application when the 'secret' key combo is pressed.

Comment: Ok.  There is a possible workaround to that.  I'll post below.

Comment: @Fraze That's an extremely mean thing to do which is both impossible to cover all cases for and also and something you shouldn't try to do anyway, as it creates a horrible user experience.  You should be allowing the close your application through whatever tools are provided by the operating system.

Comment: @Servy It's based on need.  I wouldn't recommend it for any other purpose.  This workstation will be used entirely to deliver this exam and we don't want to allow the users to exit out or use any other apps, etc.

Comment: @Fraze Don't reinvent the wheel.  Kiosks have been a thing for a long time.  There are so many possible things to get wrong, the odds of you covering them all are quite low, and if you *do* cove them all, the time you'll have spend is almost certainly nowhere near what it would cost you to just buy an existing program.

Comment: Note that my fix doesn't cover Start-R (Run Command), Ctrl-Alt-Del, Ctrl-Shift-Esc, or any of those kind of OS keystrokes.  There are a million ways a savvy user can get around this. +1 to @Servy's concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to determine the cause of a closing event to disable certain keystrokes, disable all methods for closing until your "secret" keystroke is entered.

Use a `KeyDown` event to intercept and record all keystrokes, and have it set a flag if the secret combination is entered, and then call `Close()`.

In your `Closing` event, always set `e.Cancel = true` unless that flag is set.

Here's a simple example:

```
bool _allowClose = false;

void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (DetectSecretCombo(e))  //Implement however you see fit.
    {
        _allowClose = true;
        Close();
    }
}

void OnClosing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e)
{
    _e.Cancel = !_allowClose;
}
```